# Jquery function crash internet explorer

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, internet-explorer

I made a function to clear my modals when they close, it works fine on fierfox and google chrome but it crashes internet explorer, and not using it is not an option is there some way to change it so IE can read it?

```
$(".modal-body input").val("")
(function () {
    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        $(this).removeData();
    });
});
```

Comment: You're never calling the function. Is this supposed to be `$(function ...)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the first line, should look like this:

```
$(".modal-body input").val("");
```

Without the semicolon is like using the return of `$(".modal-body input").val("")` like a function, like if it were in the same line.

To be more clear, is like if your code is put like this:

```
$(".modal-body input").val("")(function () {
    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        $(this).removeData();
    });
});
```

And breaks because `val()` does not return a function.

---

Also, the second part of your code the way you put it here does nothing, you might wanted it to be executed on document load, like this:

```
$(function () { //notice the $ at the start of the line
    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        $(this).removeData();
    });
});
```

Or right away when the code is loaded, like this:

```
(function () { //notice the $ at the start of the line
    $(".modal").on("hidden.bs.modal", function () {
        $(this).removeData();
    });
})(); //notice the extra () here
```

Comment: Thank you ! adding te semicolon at val made it work since i call it on $(document).ready(function () {  Thanks a lot really. this saved my day

Comment: Glad to know it worked. As an advice, try to use some linting tool like eslint to help you mantain code quality.